# Macro to paste Excel charts to Word works but gives error when run as an Add In

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, excel-addins

I've pieced together code to copy and paste some tables and charts from Excel into an existing Word document at bookmarked locations. When I run the macro from within a spreadsheet module everything works fine and all the data is copied over into the correct places. When I install the macro as an Add In to Excel and run it then I get an Error 5342 when it comes time to paste the chart into Word.

The chart has been copied to the clipboard as I can paste it manually and I've tried to add a DoEvents between the copying and the pasting of the chart but got the same error. And again, it works fine when run as a module within the spreadsheet so I'm not sure what's going wrong - any help would be appreciated.

```
For y = LBound(tableArray) To UBound(tableArray)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set rng = Workbooks(getWBook).Names(tableArray(y)).RefersToRange
    rng.Copy
    If wrdDoc.bookmarks.exists(tableArray(y)) Then
        With wrdDoc.bookmarks(tableArray(y)).Range
            .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
        End With
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next y

With wrdDoc.bookmarks("RQTable").Range.Tables(1)
    .autofitbehavior 2
    .Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
End With

For Each wrdTbl In wrdDoc.Tables
    With wrdTbl
        .Rows(1).Range.Font.Size = 12
    End With
Next wrdTbl

For x = LBound(chartArray) To UBound(chartArray)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wb.Charts(chartArray(x)).CopyPicture _
    Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    With wrdDoc
        If .bookmarks.exists(bookmarkArray(x)) Then
            Set wrdRng = .bookmarks(bookmarkArray(x)).Range
            wrdRng.PasteSpecial _
            Link:=False, _
            DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
            Placement:=wdInLine, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False
            .bookmarks.Add bookmarkArray(x), wrdRng
        End If
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next x
```

Comment: The code to paste a chart includes two Word enums, `wdPasteEnhancedMetafile` and `wdInLine`.  I can't be certain as your code doesn't show how you have declared `wrdDoc` or `wrdRng` but I suspect you haven't set a reference to the Word object library.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Yep, you're absolutely right. I didn't realize that I had to set the reference again in the add in. Thanks for your help

Comment: What line of code exactly gives the error? Do you still have any problems with running the code after adding a reference and adding namespaces to enums?